# Cocos2d-x Support Secondary Display?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, display, presentation

I want to show the secondary screen for using Android on Cocos2d-x.

Is there a Presentation Class in the Android that can be used with Cocos2d-x?

I want to Main UIScreen show Cocos2dx Scene or Java Controller,Ex:Move button,Pause button…

Secondary UIscreen show another Cocos2dx Scene GameScene Viewer,Ex:Role,Collider,Decorator

Is there a way to configure the Dual Display with Cocos2d-x as an Android platform?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly. If you mean secondary/external display show something different that main device,  It's none of cocos2d's business.

However, if you want to have a split-screen output like below picture, it's possible though not trivial.

[image: split-screen]

Although I didn't do something like that, I can point you towards discussions like [this](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-split-screen-or-have-variable-layer-size/35088).